rviz2 doesnt detect one of the joint/link combos in the urdf while other urdf viewers do
I'm using ROS Jazzy on Ubuntu 24. I have a URDF file written with the help of xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="my_robot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:include filename="macros.xacro"/>

  <link name="world"></link>

  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="1.5 1 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="2.5 1.5 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="green"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="2.5 1.5 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_box mass="12" x="2.5" y="1.5" z="0.1">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_box>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="slider_joint" type="prismatic">
    <origin xyz="-1.25 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="slider_link"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="0" upper="2" velocity="100" effort="100"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="slider_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.075" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
          <box size="0.5 0.25 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.075" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
          <box size="0.5 0.25 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_box mass="0.5" x="0.5" y="0.25" z="0.15">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.075" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_box>
  </link>

  <joint name="arm_joint" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0.25 0 0.15" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="slider_link"/>
    <child link="arm_link"/>
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0"/>
    <limit lower="0" upper="${pi/2}" velocity="100" effort="100"/>
  </joint>

  <xacro:property name="arm_length" value="1"/>
  <xacro:property name="arm_radius" value="0.1"/>
  <link name="arm_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="${arm_length/2} 0 0" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
      <geometry>                
          <cylinder length="${arm_length}" radius="${arm_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="orange"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="${arm_length/2} 0 0" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
      <geometry>                
          <cylinder length="${arm_length}" radius="${arm_radius}"/>
      </geometry>      
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="1.0" length="${arm_length}" radius="${arm_radius}">
      <origin xyz="${arm_length/2} 0 0 " rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
  </link>

  <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="${arm_length} 0 ${arm_radius + 0.075}"/>
        <parent link="arm_link"/>
        <child link="camera_link"/>        
  </joint>

  <link name="camera_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="-0.03 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.06 0.15 0.15" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.03 0 0" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.06" radius="0.04"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.12 0.15 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_box mass="0.1" x="0.12" y="0.15" z="0.15">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_box>
  </link>

</robot>

This is the macros.xacro file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  
  <!-- inertial calculations from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia-->

  <xacro:macro name="inertial_sphere" params="mass radius *origin">
    <inertial>
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(2/5) * mass * radius*radius}" ixy="0" ixz="0"
               iyy="${(2/5) * mass * radius*radius}" iyz="0"
               izz="${(2/5) * mass * radius*radius}"
      />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="inertial_box" params="mass x y z *origin">
    <inertial>
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(1/12) * mass * (y*y + z*z)}" ixy="0" ixz="0"
               iyy="${(1/12) * mass * (x*x + z*z)}" iyz="0"
               izz="${(1/12) * mass * (x*x + y*y)}"
      />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="inertial_cylinder" params="mass length radius *origin">
    <inertial>
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}" ixy="0" ixz="0"
               iyy="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}" iyz="0"
               izz="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}"
      />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>


  <!-- colours -->

  <material name="green">
    <color rgba="0.2 1 0.2 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="white">
    <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="orange">
    <color rgba="1 0.3 0.1 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.2 1 1"/>
  </material>


</robot>

Viewing this urdf using a VSCode extension works perfectly as expected:
viewing the urdf in VSCode
But, in rviz i get the following error:
viewing the urdf in rviz
I suspect it may have something to do with rviz not recognizing the prismatic joint? But that is just a baseless suspicion i have no idea.
I tried exporting the output of xacro to a file to see if it was an xacro issue, but it wasnt.

You have to broadcast your tf transformations for all the joints defined in the urdf file. You can publish these using a ROS node:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped
from tf2_ros import TransformBroadcaster
import math

class TFBroadcaster(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('tf_broadcaster')
        
        # Create a transform broadcaster
        self.broadcaster = TransformBroadcaster(self)
        
        # Create a timer to publish transforms periodically
        self.timer = self.create_timer(0.1, self.broadcast_transforms)  # 10Hz
        
        # Initialize joint states (you might want to subscribe to actual joint states)
        self.slider_position = 0.0
        self.arm_angle = 0.0

    def broadcast_transforms(self):
        current_time = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
        
        # Base link transform
        t = TransformStamped()
        t.header.stamp = current_time
        t.header.frame_id = 'world'
        t.child_frame_id = 'base_link'
        t.transform.translation.x = 1.5
        t.transform.translation.y = 1.0
        t.transform.translation.z = 0.0
        t.transform.rotation.w = 1.0
        self.broadcaster.sendTransform(t)
        
        # Slider link transform
        t = TransformStamped()
        t.header.stamp = current_time
        t.header.frame_id = 'base_link'
        t.child_frame_id = 'slider_link'
        t.transform.translation.x = -1.25 + self.slider_position  # Add slider position
        t.transform.translation.y = 0.0
        t.transform.translation.z = 0.1
        t.transform.rotation.w = 1.0
        self.broadcaster.sendTransform(t)
        
        # Arm link transform
        t = TransformStamped()
        t.header.stamp = current_time
        t.header.frame_id = 'slider_link'
        t.child_frame_id = 'arm_link'
        t.transform.translation.x = 0.25
        t.transform.translation.y = 0.0
        t.transform.translation.z = 0.15
        # Convert arm angle to quaternion (rotation around Y axis)
        t.transform.rotation.w = math.cos(self.arm_angle/2)
        t.transform.rotation.x = 0.0
        t.transform.rotation.y = -math.sin(self.arm_angle/2)  # Negative because of axis direction
        t.transform.rotation.z = 0.0
        self.broadcaster.sendTransform(t)
        
        # Camera link transform
        t = TransformStamped()
        t.header.stamp = current_time
        t.header.frame_id = 'arm_link'
        t.child_frame_id = 'camera_link'
        t.transform.translation.x = 2.0  # arm_length
        t.transform.translation.y = 0.0
        t.transform.translation.z = 0.175  # arm_radius + 0.075
        t.transform.rotation.w = 1.0
        self.broadcaster.sendTransform(t)

def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = TFBroadcaster()
    try:
        rclpy.spin(node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Launch the package
ros2 run <your-package> <your-node>

